# What is the meaning of the exception "Deprecated API access logged: UiApplication.popScreen()"

Tags: blackberry

When I clicked on the ListField in the popup menu it gives this exception
"Deprecated API access logged: UiApplication.popScreen()"

Answer (score 1):

You are using a deprecated method. Use [popScreen(net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html#popScreen%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen%29) of the [UiApplication](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html) instead of `popScreen()`.

> `public final void popScreen(Screen screen)`
>
> Removes a screen from the display stack, and updates the screen.
>
> **Specified by:**
>
> [`popScreen`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiEngine.html#popScreen%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen%29) in interface [`UiEngine`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiEngine.html)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `screen` - [`Screen`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html) to remove.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) - If your screen is not on the stack.